# Using SVN with Xamarin Studio. Any alternatives?

Tags: svn, xamarin

I have just started using Xamarin Studio on my macbook and want to use subversion for source control. How do i enable SVN in Xamarin? Are there any other "free" source control tools that i can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin Studio supports Subversion and Git natively - both systems have multiple free options available via self-hosting or hosted services (Github, etc).

Recent versions of OS X do not have the Subversion client installed by default.  To resolve this, install the XCode Command Line tools.  This can be done via the XCode GUI, or with this command from the shell:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

I can install cmd line tools on MAC, but Xamarin.Studio support only SVN 1.6 and older.

I'm using cmd line for SVN on MAC or VS2013 & MAC as a build host.